# reading RFID tag with Android NFC functionality

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

Hi I've been having a lot of trouble reading a particular KOVIO RFID tag with my android Galaxy Nexus. This tag isn't an NFC tag, so it doesn't contain any Ndef message or any Extra data. All I want is the tag ID, but I can't find any APIs to do it.

In my Android Manifest, I've set my intent filter to:

```
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    </intent-filter>
```

When I put the tag to my device, it makes the sound that it read it, and goes to the onPause() method and then the OnResume() method.

I've traced through both of them, and when I inspect the intent, I find that the fields mClipData, mData, mExtras, mPackage, mSelector, mSourcebounds, mType are all null. Therefore, when I do stuff like

```
    byte[] tagId = intent.getByteArrayExtra(aa);
```

tagId comes out to be null. Can anyone help me extract the ID?
I know its possible because the TagInfo app by NXP was able to display the id. I just don't know why I can't :(

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
if (intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {
  Tag tag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG));
  byte[] id = tag.getId(); // the tag's ID
}
```